# How to change shared state in Alpine.js?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, shared-state

I'm trying to hide multiple elements inside the DOM by changing shared state when window is resized.

```
<body class="font-body relative" x-data="{hideOnMobile:false}">
 <section class="mt-5" :class={'section' : !hideOnMobile , 'hidden' : hideOnMobile}">
   ...
  </section>
</body>
```

And when i try to

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
   let data = document.querySelector('[x-data]');
         
       if (window.innerWidth > 639) {
           return data.__x.$data.hideOnMobile = true;
       }
    };
```

It should change the state ** hideOnMobile** to true but it doesn't somehow any idea?

Comment: So the logic here states to hide on mobile when the window is **larger** than 639? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm guessing there's other stuff going on but in this example you could just use the tailwind breakpoint helpers e.g. `<div class="hidden sm:block">Hidden on mobile</div>`

Comment: @SteveO yes the logic is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using `@resize.window`? (ie. adding the `resize` listener using Alpine.js) it should make your code simpler than using `window.onresize` + trying to update Alpine.js `__x.$data` internal.

```html
<body
  class="font-body relative"
  x-data="{hideOnMobile:false}"
  @resize.window="hideOnMobile = window.innerWidth > 639"
>
 <section class="mt-5" :class={'section' : !hideOnMobile , 'hidden' : hideOnMobile}">
   ...
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no space before `x-data` attribute. Try to change this line:

`<body class="font-body relative"x-data="{hideOnMobile:false}">`

to this:

`<body class="font-body relative" x-data="{hideOnMobile:false}">`

Comment: I've just edited the question in my IDE there is a space in stackoverflow I missed that part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is used as an example in the AlpineJS readme. Check this out:

> .window modifier Example:

```
<div x-on:resize.window="isOpen = window.outerWidth > 768 ? false : open"></div>
```

> Adding .window to an event listener will install the listener on the
> global window object instead of the DOM node on which it is declared.
> This is useful for when you want to modify component state when
> something changes with the window, like the resize event. In this
> example, when the window grows larger than 768 pixels wide, we will
> close the modal/dropdown, otherwise maintain the same state.